# How to group list items into buckets of varying sequence lengths?

Tags: python, list, sequence, bucket

I have the following list:

```
l = [False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

I would like to accumulate the length of each True and False sequence into buckets. I need to count all sequences that are True with the sequential length = 1, then sequential length = 2, sequential length = 3 ...

An output for that list could be like:

Falses: `{1:2, 2:1, 3:1}`
Trues: `{1:3, 2:1}`

Can anybody help out a little?

> Edit: Solution
>
> ```
> from collections import defaultdict
> trues = defaultdict(int)
> l = [1 if i == True else -1 for i in l]
> seq = []
> for i in series:
>     if i > 0:
>         seq.append(i)
>     else:
>         if len(seq) != 0:
>             trues[len(seq)] += 1
>         seq = []
> if len(seq) != 0:
>     trues[len(seq)] += 1
> print(trues)
> >defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {2: 1, 1: 3})
> ```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show that you've made an attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm unsure why this was closed. The question clearly states intent although without showing an attempt

Comment: Your question has been reopened. Since you already solved it yourself, instead of putting the answer in a question you can put that solution into a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). And here's a tip for your next question: it would be good if you provided your own attempts at solving the problem, then post that attempt with the question, even if it isn't working. The community welcomes problems where the asker has shown some effort.

Answer (score 0):

This can be via `itertools.groupby` and `Counter`:

```
l = [False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]

from collections import Counter
import itertools

Counter(sum(1 for item in group) 
        for head, group in itertools.groupby(l) 
        if head == True) # => Counter({1: 3, 2: 1})
```

`groupby` constructs runs of equal items then these are filtered by their head item and the length of each of their group generators is taken and these are given to `Counter`.